# Paginate data with offset on an non order firestore query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I use offset and limit to paginate query, do I need to specify an order?
In other words, a query with no order specified, uses some implicit order, like key order?

In a SQL database, if I don't specify an order, SQL engine will return the results in the order he pleases. So the second time the query is run, the results may be staked in a different order, so offset and limit would not cut the result as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption you want to order your documents by creation date, in Firestore this would need an extra field, as explained in the Firestore documentation ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)):

> Unlike "push IDs" in the Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore
>   auto-generated IDs do not provide any automatic ordering. If you want
>   to be able to order your documents by creation date, you should store
>   a timestamp as a field in the documents.

Comment: I guess the only order that prevents new inserts from popping up in the middle is order by creation date, or something that reflects creation order, so i accept the answer.